# Unions of SVG Point Markers In QGIS?

Tags: qgis, symbology, markers, svg, union

I am attempting to understand if (and how) I might persuade QGIS to perform a union operation on the ***drawing*** of the marker symbols (not the geometry itself) based on a series of ***points***.  It's easy to set up SVG markers, but let's say that what I see after doing so is this:

[image: Symbols Rendered Individually]

What I'd like to see, however, is this:

[image]

I know this is easily accomplished if the green circles were actual polygon geometries, but what I'm wanting united (unioned?) are the SVG marker symbols as drawn on the screen/printed - not the point data.

If this is possible, then how?

Comment: Have you considered mapping with regular symbols, export your project as svg and then re-work it using Inkscape or Illustrator ? This is a piece of cake with a vector-editing software but I don't know if it's even possible with QGIS. You might also reconsider using this kind of symbol as you could loose clarity on dense area (if you use proportional circles) imho.

Comment: I had thought of that, or something like it,but the more I can do in one place the better.  One thing I had in mind for this was tree canopy coverage, which would be helpful to see on the fly.  Thanks for the comment though, as this it prompted me to try out Inkscape as a finishing tool, and it worked out very well indeed!  I rather love open source software!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since your symbol are quiet simple, you can use a `simple marker` and set the blending mode to `lighten`

[image]