# Dynamic buffer regroup

Tags: qgis, buffer, geometry-generator, grouping, dynamic

I am using QGIS 3.16 and I want to create a dynamic buffer around a layer of points, so that every time I move some point the buffer also moves.
I have succeed by duplicating the layer and then symbolizing by geometry generator with the expression "buffer($geometry,10000)" but the problem is that the buffers overlap and I would like them to be a group

Is there any other way to solve it? I've heard of an expression single_sided_buffer( $geometry, distance, segments, join) but I don't know if that's the purpose of it
[image]

[image]

Comment: try setting the [blending mode](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/261121/unions-of-svg-point-markers-in-qgis/261123#261123)

Comment: @JGH: Blending doesn't seem to work for transparent symbols.

Comment: @Erik Thanks! Interesting... the blending of transparent polygon considers only the boundaries, so only the intersection between the boundaries (=points) are blended

Comment: In your ```Geometry Generator``` function you need to collect the ```geometry``` first. Like ```buffer(collect($geometry),100)```. Blending Mode should be Layer: ```Normal``` and Feature: ```Lighten```

Comment: just turn your point to a multipoint before buffering so your expression become : 'buffer (collect($geometry),10000)'. by the way you dont need to duplicate your layer, you just have to add a symbol layer in the layer styling tab

Comment: Thank you very much! I know, there's no need to duplicate the layer but I like to have two of them so I can choose which one I want to activate